# Creating percentages within certain rows in access database?

Tags: ms-access

I'm using Access 2010 and within my database I'm trying to calculate the percentages of certain rows that come from the same mapsheet. I have 3 columns in my database, one for the mapsheetID, assigned class cover and lastly the area. There are over 100 of these mapsheets, and each mapsheet can have atleast 14 different classes. I know the answer must be pretty simple, can someone please help me?

Comment: Sample data would help: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this

```
SELECT tableMapSheet.[assigned class], Count([assigned class]) AS countAssignClass, 
            [countAssignClass]*100/DCount("*","tableMapSheet") AS percentage
    FROM tableMapSheet
    GROUP BY tableMapSheet.[assigned class];
```

You should consider to save the DCount in an extra field/variable/etc. and reuse it, so it has not not be calculated for each row.